# Several listView in one activity

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have to use about 3-4 listView in one Activity. I know how I can use one listView, but when I need use more than 1 it's really issue for me. Before I asked you I have googled it a lot, but nothing.. If you have usefull links for me - you are welcome.
I get data from Parse.com (I check it and connection is correct) then I need to dispay it in each listView. 1 column = 1 listView, I have 3-4 columns.

It's my dish_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/soup"
        />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/garnish"
        />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/starter"
        />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/salad"
        />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/drink"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

It's ListActivity.class

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dish_view);
    soupView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
    garnishView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.garnish);
    starterView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.starter);
    saladView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.salad);
    drinkView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drink);

final List<String> soupList = new ArrayList<>();

List<String> garnishList = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> starterList = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> saladList = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> drinkList = new ArrayList<>();

ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Dishes");
query.selectKeys(Arrays.asList("soup"));
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    @Override
    public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            for (ParseObject object : list) {
                soupList.add(object.getString("soup"));
                System.out.println(soupList);
            }
        }
    }
});
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, soupList);
soupView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

}

And dish.xml, how display it

```
<!-- language: xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/dish"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try expandable list view - http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

Comment: I just noticed, if I delete all listView and allow leave only 1 listView it's pretty work..

Comment: Suppose we do no need file dish.xml, I can make my work without this file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try assigning each listview a weight. Example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/soup"
    />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/garnish"
    />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/starter"
    />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/salad"
    />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/drink"
    />
```

And you should populate the list and set the Adapter when you receive your data. Try this:

```
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
@Override
public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {
        String[] items = new String[list.size()];
        int i = 0;
        for (ParseObject object : list) {
            items[i] = object.getString("soup");
            i++;
            System.out.println(soupList);
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(ListActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
        soupView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
});
```

Comment: Still nothing.. I don't know what happens, but now program doesn't display even only soup.. Code - same like above

Comment: ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, soupList); - here error "Unchecked assignment Adapter to Adapter<String>

Comment: Probably you are still using jdk 6, then it should be: ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(blah blah)

Comment: Mimmo Grottoli, thank you, buddy!) I didn't stop google my problem, your XML works. I try to do my app with no parse, just with String[]. But I still have problem like, how I can chenge my code, cause I need to inflate ListView from Parse

Comment: No, I use jdk 7.. Here is location /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle

Comment: Have you tried my last solution? First fill the List, then create the adapter and at last set the adapter.

Comment: I changed as you sad to me: ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, soupList.toArray(new String[soupList.size()])); Still error :(

Comment: I have only jdk. java -version
java version "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)

Comment: Can you explain me 2 things please? 1 - why your first code didn't work in my android-studio? 2 - If some column has 4 rows and others have 5 - I'll get exception.. How can I handle it? For example, I have 3 soup, but only 2 drink, do you know what I should do in this case?

Comment: Post code. It's difficult to imagine in this way :)

Comment: 1) ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(ListActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items); won't work without ListActivity(only ListActivity.this). And 2) - http://i61.tinypic.com/4tuc09.png in this case I'll get exception

Comment: Ok. ListActivity.this is required since you're in an inner class and this refers to the inner class while ListActivity.this refers to the outer class (that is what you need)

Comment: About the exception, I still don't understand.

Comment: Sometimes, even my app still working and I didn't change anything I got this exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: ParseObject has no data for 'starter'. Call fetchIfNeeded() to get the data. After I got it, I just 2-3 times reRun it and it'll work.. Where the stuff?

Comment: Just found I need to use query like saladList.add(object.fetchIfNeeded().getString("salad")); with method fetchIfNeeded(). And after it i got no exception..